# Order By Highest Level MYSQL PHP (Runescape Clan Highscores)

Tags: php, mysql

**Updated to give better explanation:**

I'm in the process of trying to create a highscores feature for my clan on a game called runescape but i don't know how to sort the leaderboard by "total level"

[Working Demo without sorting by total level](http://mcbuffalo.com/playground/osrs/)

For example silenthawk should be top because he has a total of 1,941. I have a table called rsusers with the columns **id, rank and playername**

I'm doing a sql query to get all the people from the clan and then getting the highscores off the runescape website by using a page called oldschoolhiscore.php that i found on github ([linked here](https://github.com/tyler-shaw/osrs-hiscores)) - I think all i have to do is edit this page to sort by the 'total level' but i'm not sure?

Here is very stripped down and simple demo and code:

[Demo here](http://mcbuffalo.com/playground/osrs/basic.php)

Code:

```
        <?php

    require 'OldSchoolHiscore.php';


    $dbhost = 'localhost';  
    $dbuser = 'xxxx';  
    $dbpass = 'xxxxxxxxx';  
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');  
    $dbname = 'xxxxxx';  
    $connection = mysql_select_db($dbname);  


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rsusers";  
    $rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);  


    ?>  



        <table class="table table-striped table-list-search">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Level</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>


            <?php  

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_result)) { 



                $hs = new OldSchoolHiscore($row['username']);


                $total_level = $hs->getSkillLevel('overall');

                echo "<tr>";

                echo "<td>".$row['username']."</td>";
                echo "<td>$total_level</td>";


                echo "</tr>";




            }

            ?>  

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

SQL

```
    INSERT INTO rsusers 
(username, clanrank)
VALUES 
('Dwh_Hunters', 'lieutenant'),
('SilentHawk', 'general'),
('Sir Novel', 'lieutenant'),
('Ryuk Yagami', 'general');
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Use **[ORDER BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)**

Try with

```
 $sql = ('SELECT * FROM rsusers ORDER BY level DESC');
```

Comment: And you probably want to add some header sort capabilitie. Check something like this. http://phppot.com/php/sorting-mysql-column-using-php/

Comment: I don't have a column level, it gets everyones username from the table and then grabs the relevent info after the query.

Comment: @ChristopherWard Then put everything in a 2-D array, and use `usort()` to sort the array by the `level` field.

Comment: As @Barmar said. Or you modify your query to bring everything at once. Because looks like you are executing a query for each user, and that isn't efficient.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza That's assuming functions like `getSkillLevel()` are doing database queries.

Comment: I tried using usort earlier but i don't know what i'm doing or where to put it. i got the error "expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in". Any chance you could show me what to do.

Comment: Yes that is my bet @Barmar, because he is using the user object to get that info.

Comment: I'm still having trouble if anyone knows what i'm trying to do and how to do it.